# Facing an error 'Could not load a driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS''

Tags: xcode, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

unable to start the appium inspector it throws the error

Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not load a driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS'. Please verify your Appium installation

appium version - 1.22.3
xcode - 15

downloaded the latest version of wda and replaced with the existing wda after that i'm facing the issue above, i got struck in it can someone help to solve this.